# Cannot find GameController script - causing errors with logging and references

Tags: unity, c#

I am learning the Unity engine and have been practicing with various tutorials, but there is a curious error I am experiencing with the space shooter tutorial. Collisions with the player ship do not destroy asteroids or the player, while collisions with bolts fired by the player will destroy the asteroids but not increase the score at all.

The error being logged is "Cannot find GameController script" which makes me think there is a problem with my code below, specifically the void Start() function that checks if GameController != null.

Is there something about Unity 5 that differs from Unity 4 that I would need to change? Or have I made a mistake in this code attempting to reference the GameController script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject explosion;
    public GameObject playerExplosion;
    public int scoreValue;
    private GameController gameController;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject gameControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController");
        if (gameController != null)
        {
            gameController = gameControllerObject.GetComponent<GameController>();
        }
        if (gameController == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Cannot find 'GameController' script");
        }
    } 

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Boundary")
        {
            return;
        }
        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Instantiate(playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
            gameController.GameOver();
        }

        Debug.Log(other.name);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        gameController.AddScore(scoreValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're most-likely doing a wrong check in the **Start** function and it should read

```
if (gameControllerObject != null)
{
 ...
}
```

because you're trying to find the controller object by tag and have to verify that the return value of `GameObject.FindWithTag(...)` is not `null`. Otherwise you might risk running into a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the game object tagged as GameController. See image.

[image]